# CodenameOne CodeScanner on iOS

Tags: codenameone

We are trying to scan qr code and bar codes in one of our app.
We are currently using the com.codename1.ext.codescan.CodeScanner to do the scanning.

The scanning seems to work on most devices but we have a few users complaining that the scanning is not working.

The scanner open up correctly but it refuses to scan any barcode.

Comment: Which barcodes is it failing to scan? Notice that there are multiple types of barcodes and some perform better than others with the standard zbar scanner.